# How does .Net handle concurrent network traffic on the same NIC adapter?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, ffmpeg, network-programming

I am having an issue with my .Net application where I am trying to do two things concurrently on the same NIC. This NIC handles my LAN traffic and my internet traffic. I have an IP camera on my LAN that is streaming video, which I receive and process in my app via FFMPEG. The frames come in at 10fps and each time there is a frame, an event handler is raised which contains the frame so I can process it.

In addition to this, my application is also making RESTful Web API calls to the internet, every minute, which I have set up on a `System.Threading.Timer`. The hope was that with the timer, the Web API calls would happen concurrently and not affect my video frames event handler.

However, intermittently, when my timer ticks and I make the Web API call, I will drop a few frames on the network camera. It is hard to troubleshoot if the issue is FFMPEG or the network itself (ie the frames not even getting to FFMPEG to begin with). I say intermittently because this doesn't happen everytime I make the Web API call, but when it does happen it is always when I am doing the API call. It also seems to happen more often when the API call takes a bit longer to complete.

So, my question is, how does .Net handle the NIC in a situation like this? Is it expected to run in to performance bottlenecks if two threads are trying to access the NIC at the same time? I have monitored, via task manager, the network traffic and I am nowhere near 100% so it isn't that I am flooding the network (which I would expect dropped packets at that point). It has to be something with how .Net handles access to the NIC from the same process, even if from two different threads?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb comment but are you sure the issue is the NIC? `System.Threading.Timer` runs the callback (i.e. your API call) on a threadpool thread, and 10fps is one frame each 100ms. So depending on how long it takes to process each frame and the characteristics of your machine, and how your event handler is implemented (may be a good idea to post the code here), couldn't it be that when the API call is made, even if only one thread is used, the threadpool runs out of available threads and until a new one is created or available some frames are discarded?

Comment: @evilmandarine Thank you for the response, not a dumb comment at all! If anything, I am doing something dumb. You are correct, it may not be the NIC and I am sure it is me. I assumed that running my API call, which I wanted to do at interval, in a System.Threading.Timer, that it would execute on a different thread and not affect the other things I am doing with frames coming in via an event handler. Is that thinking not accurate and the two can still fight each other?

Comment: It is executing on a different thread but it is a [threadpool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/the-managed-thread-pool) thread. More about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2003/june/net-column-the-clr-s-thread-pool). So if your processing also uses one thread per frame from the pool, the API call could cause frames being dropped (no more threads available). But it's hard to say without seeing the code. You could try to explicitly create your own thread for that call, and also measure how long one frame processing takes.